# How to have submit and field validation at the same time in formik?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, formik

i want to validate form on submit with formik, while also have field level validation.For example, validate all fields when submitting, and validate a field on change.

```
 return (
    <div className='add-member'>
      <h1>Register a new member</h1>
      <Formik
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        validateOnBlur={false}
        validateOnChange={false}
        initialValues={{ name: ''}}
        onSubmit={() => {
          console.log('something')
        }}
      >
        {({errors}) => (
          <Form>
            <div className='member-info'>
              <div className='title'><p>Info</p></div>
        
              <div className='input' id='name-input'>
                <label>Name</label>
                <Field name='name' placeholder={errors.name ? '*Required' : null} className={errors.name ?      'input-error' : ''} />
              </div>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  )
```

I have disabled validateOnChange in the Formik component so that submit validation works, but dont know how to validate a field on change.

Comment: And why does validation triggers on all fields whenever i change or use unfocus one field ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to do form validation using Yup with validationSchema.
And also you should use `useFormik` hook instead of `Formik` component.

Then you may reach the correct response.

For example

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema: registrationSchema,
... the code that you want
```

```
const registrationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
fieldName: Yup.string()
.oneOf([Yup.ref('')], "example commit"),
```

Maybe, you will get success.

Comment: I tried using yup but couldnt make field level validation. One blur or change activated all fields validations.Perhaps there is a way with handeBlur or something. Since i read that formik is no longer maintained i switched to use form hook.

Comment: Now, don't you get success?

Comment: What do you mean? I didnt manage it. I switched to use hook form, so far so good.